# amchart separate bullets individually

Tags: html, css, amcharts

I am creating a simple time-based data plot using `amcharts` with has 5 values, its working great but every time there is 2 or more readings with the same value it stack up and only 1 bullet is visible, i tried to create a custom bullet but still no luck.

Is there a way to separate the bullets individually just to make it presentable.

[image]

Below is my code.

```
{
                            "bullet": "round",
                            "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
                            "bulletColor": "#2980b9",
                            "bulletSize": 19,
                             "customBulletField": "bullet",
                            "id": "reading_4",
                            "lineThickness": 0,
                            "title": "reading_4",
                            "showHandOnHover": true, 
                            "valueField": "column-8",
                            "balloonText": "<div style='margin:5px; font-size:12px;'>Reading 4: <b>[[value]]</b></div>",
                            "visibleInLegend": false,

                        },
```

Is there away to make it like below

[image]

Comment: The only way to make it look like that is to give each of those points different timestamps. There's also [bulletOffset](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#bulletOffset) but that will likely not work well.There isn't a way otherwise to move individual bullets to always prevent overlap. Consider using a chartCursor so at least all the bullet balloons will show when hovering over that point in time in your chart.